# ERROR AL DESPLEGAR APLICACION IIS EN WINDOWS SERVER

Tags: c#, api, iis, c#-8.0, com

Tengo un problema al intentar montar una aplicación `C# ASPNET CORE` en `IIS`, cuando intento llamar alguna de la funciones que hace uso de una referencia `COM` el servidor se queda cargando pero nunca pasa de ahí, cabe destacar que ya le di permisos sobre las carpetas de la carpeta donde están las `.dll` también intenten montar el `IIS` en mi equipo local y funciona perfectamente, pero en `Windows server` no funciona.

**Permisos de las carpetas:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Configuración de IIS:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La aplicación usa bibliotecas `COM` en `32Bits` por lo que habilite la compatibilidad,

Comment: ¿Qué dicen los Logs?

Comment: ¿Cómo los puedo ver? perdón por la pregunta estúpida pero soy muy nuevo en IIS

Comment: Creo que "Ver logs IIS" en google puede que arroje resultados pertinentes.

Comment: Ninguna pregunta es estúpida, quizás mal estructurada o mal redactada, en fin,  botón inicio -> Event Viewer -> Windows Logs y demás logs . Buena suerte. Saludos :D

Comment: https://mid.as/kb/00211/how-to-enable-detailed-iis-errors
ve esa página web, ahí enseña a habilitar los errores con detalles, en la página te dice que utilices la opcion "detail errors" pero es mejor "detail errors for local...". Luego de esto intenta cargar tu sitio en el mismo servidor y si falla te mostrará detalles del o los errores, de esta forma es mas fácil buscar soluciones

Comment: Gracias fredyfx y LPZadkiel por la ayuda voy a probar y actualizo la pregunta con los logs

Comment: Venga que también Arriel te está ayudando, aunque "no parezca", justamente ir a un buscador es lo que hace falta en especial cuando uno inicia, después, seguirás buscando (llevo como 20 años programando desde mi primer hola mundo en el colegio) aunque con mayor determinación y un nivel mayor de certeza.

Comment: Creo que no hace falta decir que ya busque en google, normalmente cuando preguntamos en un foro como stackoverflow es por que agotamos todas las soluciones encontradas en google. la empatia tambien es importante al momento de ayudar.

Comment: Lo que dices es lo ideal y considerando esa visión que tienes, te sorprenderías de la cantidad enorme de usuarios nuevos y usuarios que llevan tiempo en SOes que realizan preguntas sin investigación (y ni han usado el buscador del mismo SOes -> por eso hay preguntas duplicadas o muy parecidas), sin intentos y para variar, algunos usuarios exigen respuestas urgentes. Sí, definitivamente la empatía es importante; considera que es normal "invitar a buscar en google" o en otro buscador cuando una pregunta que carece de detalles de investigación y/o intentos, nadie lo dice en mal plan.

Answer (score 0):

Al parecer el problema no era de `IIS` si no mas bien de `Windows server` investigando un poco mas gracias a los comentarios de @Fredyfx y @LPZadkiel Y montando un servidor de `IIS` de prueba, descubri que windows server me estaba bloqueando el uso de librerias `COM` esto lo resolvi editando el registro de windows.

Comment: Me alegra que hayas solucionado el tema :D por favor, edita la respuesta e incluye qué registros modificaste, lo que hubo y lo que quedó luego de la modificación, de este modo, serás el héroe de más usuarios que tengan el mismo escenario/problema y de paso, la respuesta tendrá una buena calidad. Recuerda marcarla como aceptada luego de 24 horas para ayudar a mantener la buena salud del sitio (% de preguntas resueltas). Saludos.

Comment: Me dirijo a Daniel Correa o alguien que me pueda ayudar acerca de este caso.
Me ha pasado algo parecido con el IIS pero no logro descubrir ni con los logs de error.
Haces referencia a que no era de IIS sino del S.O. Podías indicar el detalle de las entradas de registro que alteraste?
Gracias por anticipado. Un saludo